# How many key frames have been encoded in my video? ffmpeg was the encoder used

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, key, frameset

I am attempting to add a keyframe every second using "-g 25" as an option with ffmpeg.

I need a way however, to query the output video, and other videos on my server to see how many keyframes have been encoded.

Is there an ffmpeg command line attribute which will tell me this information? Or any other tool? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that ffmpeg has a command line argument for such a specialized query. You can, however, write your own program using the ffmpeg library, where you traverse the entire video stream and check each frame if it is a key frame.

struct AVFrame has a member int key_frame which is 1 for a key frame and 0 otherwise.